# How to get all data except last query?

Tags: laravel

I have this foreach I need to get all data except last one that I current add it

my foreach :

```
 @foreach ($user->projects->sortByDesc('id')->except() as $porject)

  // my data

 @endforeach
```

projects is relation between `user` and `projects` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pop() collection [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pop) that removes the last item. I would do it in the controller and share the projects with the view.

```
$projects = $user->projects()->orderBy('id')->get();
$projects->pop();

return view('view', compact('user', 'projects'))
```

Comment: Change the sortBy and you should be going :)

Comment: Also updated it to sort by in the database which imo is more optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Going from your code you could use [`take(n)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#take):

```
@foreach ($user->projects->sortByDesc('id')->take($user->projects->count() - 1) as $porject)

// my data

@endforeach
```

or you could use [`$loop->last`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable) and just render when it's not the last item:

```
@foreach ($user->projects->sortByDesc('id') as $porject)
@if (! $loop->last)
// my data
@endif
@endforeach
```

or you could use `pop()` (as @mrhnn suggested) with [`tap()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-tap):

```
@foreach (tap($user->projects->sortByDesc('id'))->pop() as $porject)
// my data
@endforeach
```